# Can I get SSD rw performance while keeing data security if I combine SSD & HDD in RAID1

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, raid, btrfs

I have 2 storage devices; classical slow HDD( 750GB, /dev/sda ) and faster SSD( 128GB, /dev/sdb ). Currently I have installed Ubuntu & Mint on same btrfs partition on SSD ( /dev/sdb5 ). My btrfs pool consists of /dev/sdb5/

What I want to achieve is data replication on HDD while keeping SSD performance: Something like this:

For read case it would be ideal for procedure to go like this:

- read from SSD
- check checksum
- if it verifies.. awesome, give me the data
- if not, fetch data from HDD and perform error correction through duplicate data

I'd manually run (some tool I'm not sure which one... btrfs check --repair perhaps?) every month or so to check HDD checksums and corrected them via SSD data against bitrot.

For write case:

- write to SSD
- sync to HDD when write requirements are low, thus not slowing down the system.

Is this possible and how would I do it?

Comment: I doubt askubuntu is the place to ask this (when I search for raid 1 http://unix.stackexchange.com pops up more than AU) and I also doubt this is possible.   "hybrid RAID1" yes is possible. You set the set the disks during creation as "write-mostly" and that will cause the kernel to only do (slow) reads from the HDD if they are really needed. All other reads will go to the SSD.  But what you want with checksums... doubt it, unless you can fabricate something yourself.

Answer (score 0):

bcache and dm-cache can use a disk like a SSD as a writeback cache. flashcache and rapiddisk are interesting too. All of them add lots of complexity to your storage stack, if you don't know what you're doing you can easily lose data.

Honestly, for a general purpose OS workload, it's probably a complete waste of time. These sort of stacks are targeted at IO intensive applications like databases. If you're just trying to experiment I would suggest setting up a different data disk target so you can tinker without wiping out your operating system. Use fio or vdbench to measure your perf.